# Mapping TimeSpan in SQLite and Dapper

Tags: c#, sqlite, orm, dapper, system.data.sqlite

I'm attempting to use Dapper to interface to an existing database format that has a table with a duration encoded as ticks in a BIGINT column.  How do I tell Dapper to map my POCO's `TimeSpan`-typed property to ticks when inserting into and reading from the database?

I've tried to set the type map for `TimeSpan` to `DbType.Int64`:

```
SqlMapper.AddTypeMap(typeof(TimeSpan), DbType.Int64);
```

And I've also created an `ITypeHandler`, but the `SetValue` method is never called:

```
public class TimeSpanToTicksHandler : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<TimeSpan>
{
    public override TimeSpan Parse(object value)
    {
        return new TimeSpan((long)value);
    }

    public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, TimeSpan value)
    {
        parameter.Value = value.Ticks;
    }
}
```

Here's my POCO:

```
public class Task
{
    public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }

    // etc.
}
```

When executing a simple insert statement like this:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO Tasks (Duration) values (@Duration);";
```

And passing the POCO as the object to insert:

```
Task task = new Task { Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20) };
connection.Execute(sql, task);
```

I get this exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
   at System.Convert.ToInt64(Object value, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteStatement.BindParameter(Int32 index, SQLiteParameter param)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteStatement.BindParameters()
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.BuildNextCommand()
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.GetStatement(Int32 index)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteCommand(IDbConnection cnn, ref CommandDefinition command, Action`2 paramReader) in SqlMapper.cs: line 3310
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteImpl(IDbConnection cnn, ref CommandDefinition command) in SqlMapper.cs: line 1310
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.Execute(IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) in SqlMapper.cs: line 1185
```

If I leave the `TimeSpan` type mapping as-is (it defaults to `DbType.Time`), it writes the string version of the `TimeSpan`, i.e. `00:00:20.000", which isn't helpful as it does not match the format of the other data in the column.

Comment: I've always solved this by creating a second property that does the translation from the DB type to my type.

Answer (score 3):

Could you do the following instead?

```
public class Task
{
    public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
    public long Ticks 
    { 
        get { return Duration.Ticks; }
        set { Duration = new TimeSpan(value); }
    }
    // etc.
}

string sql = "INSERT INTO Tasks (Duration) values (@Ticks);";
```

Comment: I could, though as a Dapper newbie I was hoping there was something the library provided.  It seems like there should be with all the `ITypeHandler` and other such interfaces...

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to convert between `TimeSpan` and `DbType.Int64`, and I also found that the `SetValue` method on my `ITypeHandler` implementation was is never called.

I found that in addition to registering my type **handler**, I had to remove the type **maps** for both `TimeSpan` and `TimeSpan?`:

```
SqlMapper.RemoveTypeMap(typeof(TimeSpan));
SqlMapper.RemoveTypeMap(typeof(TimeSpan?));

SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(new TimeSpanToTicksHandler());


public class TimeSpanToTicksHandler : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<TimeSpan>
{
    public override TimeSpan Parse(object value)
    {
        return new TimeSpan((long)value);
    }

    public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, TimeSpan value)
    {
        parameter.Value = value.Ticks;
    }
}
```

Using Dapper 1.50.5.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions for LinqToDB:

```
MappingSchema.SetDataType(typeof(TimeSpan), DataType.NText);
```

Or:

```
MappingSchema.SetDataType(typeof(TimeSpan), DataType.Int64);
```

Example:

```
    public class Program
{
    private const string ConnectionString = "Data Source=:memory:;Version=3;New=True;";

    public static void Main()
    {
        var dataProvider = new SQLiteDataProvider();

        var connection = dataProvider.CreateConnection(ConnectionString);
        connection.Open();

        var dataConnection = new DataConnection(dataProvider, connection);

        dataConnection.MappingSchema.SetDataType(typeof(TimeSpan), DataType.Int64);

        dataConnection.CreateTable<Category>();

        dataConnection.GetTable<Category>()
            .DataContextInfo
            .DataContext
            .Insert(new Category
            {
                Id = 2,
                Time = new TimeSpan(10, 0, 0)
            });


        foreach (var category in dataConnection.GetTable<Category>())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($@"Id: {category.Id}, Time: {category.Time}");
        }
    }

    private class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `MappingSchema.SetDataType(typeof(TimeSpan), DataType.NText);` this fails on insert with error`MappingSchema.SetDataType(typeof(TimeSpan), DataType.Int64);` works for insert but causes exception to be raised on select `System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

Comment: to make it works `dataConnection.MappingSchema.SetDataType(typeof(TimeSpan), DataType.Int64);` has to be executed for each new connection instance. I've tried to set it once like `LinqToDB.Mapping.MappingSchema.Default.SetDataType(typeof(TimeSpan), DataType.Int64)` but no luck